# Backbone getting data from nested json

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, nested

My Json array is as follow how to extract Name and temp using Backbone

```
{
  "message": "accurate",
  "cod": "200",
  "count": 10,
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 495260,
      "name": "Shcherbinka",
      "coord": {
        "lon": 37.559719,
        "lat": 55.499722
      },
      "main": {
        "temp": 274.72,
        "pressure": 1033,
        "humidity": 93,
        "temp_min": 272.04,
        "temp_max": 277.04
      },
      "dt": 1444968405,
      "wind": {
        "speed": 2,
        "deg": 300
      },
      "sys": {
        "country": ""
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 76
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 803,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "broken clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ]
    },
```

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
<script>


      $(function() {
                var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend();

                var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                    model: Profile,
                    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=10&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f",     
                    parse : function(response){
                    weather_data = response.list
                    console.log(weather_data)
                        return weather_data;  
                   }   
                });   

                var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
                    el: "#profiles",
                    template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
                    render: function(eventName) {
                        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
                            var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
                            $(this.el).append(profileTemplate);
                        }, this);

                        return this;
                    }
                });

                var profiles = new ProfileList();  
                profiles.fetch();
                var profilesView = new ProfileView({model: profiles});
                profiles.fetch({
                    success: function() {
                        profilesView.render();
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

How to get `Name` and `temperature` from above Json , they are in different Json object inside Json object

Comment: Do you need other data attributes aswell? Do attributes change during the lifetime of the application? Will you need event listeners? Do you need to save the model to the server?

Answer (score 1):

by

> How to get Name and temperature from above Json

if you meant to access 'name' and 'temp', you can access them as follows once they are set in a model.

```
model.get("name");  //"Shcherbinka"
model.get("main").temp; //274.72
```